# How to tell Vim buffers to correctly follow the size of the terminal window?

Tags: debugging

It didn't behave like that in the past, but since a few months when a terminal window is resized, buffers are resized in a pretty weird manner.

The cursor can even locate itself outside of the displayed text.

It happens when the terminal is resized in width.

[image: behaviour example]

The cursor in the right hand side buffer is located inside a true line (if you yank from there and paste it inside of the left hand side buffer you'll copy something).

The display isn't trusty : a blank line can contain text.

Comment: Does C-L or `:redraw[!]` help?

Comment: ^L does work, :redraw[!] doesn't. Do you know what is the associated command so that I can imagine a solution to launch it on window resize in an automatic manner ?

Comment: Control-L calls either `:redraw` or `:redraw!`, I forget which, so it’s odd they didn’t work (perhaps my notation with square brackets as “optionally” wasn’t clear?). There is an autocommand (i think) for resizing